# print function in python3.x?

Tags: printing, python-3.x

I want to know how print function works. But I can't find print function in python3.2's source code!

In python2.5 print an integer(print 100, for example), will call int_print(). Because when create an int object, initialize PyIntObject's function pointer - tp_print that point to int_print():

```
printfunc tp_print;
/* We can't provide a full compile-time check that limited-API
   users won't implement tp_print. However, not defining printfunc
   and making tp_print of a different function pointer type
   should at least cause a warning in most cases. */
typedef int (*printfunc)(PyObject *, FILE *, int);
```

In python3.x, all integer is an object of PyLongObject, but it initialize tp_print=NULL. And print is a function not like python2.x.
Please tell me when call print, how it works! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I have already known! When print a builtin object, print() will call builtin_print() function.

```
builtin_print(PyObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
```